# need LCCS SDK - can not get it from adobe site anymore

Tags: adobe, livecycle, lccs

Adobe LiveCycle collaboration has now stopped but I need the LCCS SDK to test something in my computer. i can no longer download it from adobe site. Can somebody give me this SDK that they have already downloaded.

I can not login to this page because it says I don't have a non-SDK account and there is no longer an option to create one.
https://cocomo.acrobat.com/

Comment: this isn't the site to be asking to get software that you're not licensed for (you should contact Adobe directly for that).